# Restrict Time Period for Facebook FQL link_stat query

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to restrict the time period for Facebook FQL queries for link_stat data?  For example, the following query gives the link_stat data to date for google:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http://www.google.com%27
```

It appears possible to restrict the time period for other Facebook queries using "until" and "since" parameters - see this post: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#paging.  Does anyone know if its possible to do the same thing (or something similar) for link_stat queries?  Basically, I'm interested in seeing how many people liked/shared an url during a specific time period.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `link_stat` table contains only the actual stats. It cannot be queried in a historical fashion like you desire. So no, it's not possible.

Furthermore, FQL is only usable with a Graph API v2.0 app, and will be deprecated on August 7th, 2016 entirely.

Comment: Do you know of any other way to query historical statistics of url likes/shares?  Outside of using link_stat?  I know that FQL is deprecated - only need to find something that will work on a temporary basis.

Comment: No, there is none. You have to build the historical data set yourself by periodically calling the Graph API.